# How does ASP.NET MVC work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

About asp.net mvc,I want to know:what's the different from asp.net web form ? And what's the lifecycle? And where are extension points ?

Comment: Take a look at [link1](http://www.howmvcworks.net/) [link2](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/gopalk/archive/2009/01/20/how-does-asp-net-mvc-work.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best question for this site, as it doesn't fit into Q&A format of SO. Do some research before:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx

and then come back if you have a *specific* question.

Comment: I just wrote an article which may help you with undertanding the lifecycle: http://blog.christopheargento.net/2012/06/11/detailed-life-cycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request/